# Web interface to compile LaTeX on private server

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, overleaf-toolkit

I want to use `LaTeX` to write technical documentation. I need to create tex files on a computer which doesn't have pdflatex installed.

The pdflatex is installed on a Linux server with `Apache` server.

I see the solution of Overleaf but I would like to find a solution without container technology (docker, lxc or other).
Is it possible to install Overleaf without Docker ?

Comment: This depends largely on what your desired workflow is I think. You could use a regular text editor or a special-purpose LaTeX editor on the client pc to write the `.tex` files and write a small script to upload the files to your server, compile them, and download the pdf or the error messages. Or you could write a simple web interface yourself with a textbox for the LaTeX code and a compile button, and maybe some file management. Alternatively you could use the standard online version of Overleaf on their servers. Or install LaTeX on your client machine.

Comment: So, maybe you can provide some more details on what kind of setup you want, why, and which alternatives would not be possible (and why)?

Comment: The best solution will be Overleaf without Docker.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however the situation (and therefore the most appropriate solution) is still a bit unclear. Why is Overleaf without Docker your preferred approach? What is the reason that you can't or don't want to use Docker on the server? What is the reason that you don't want to use the standard Overleaf enviroment on overleaf.com? Why is it a problem to install LaTeX locally on the client? Who are the intended users and what is their technical level? How diverse is the documentation that you are planning to write?

Comment: I need to use the standards of my company and docker is not available. I need to work on an offline network (without Internet).

Comment: Definitely no need for Overleaf if you don't want it. Surely there is some kind of server side scripting set up on the server (PHP, etc.) that can call external programs. For example I wrote [this journal typesetting framework](https://bitbucket.org/frabjous/journal-tools) for use with one of my servers (–I don't use apache but any PHP-capable server would work afaik–) using [this online LaTeX editor](https://bitbucket.org/frabjous/journal-tools). But I encourage you to develop your own solution if you want.

Comment: https://texlive.net/run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by creating my own application.
I use a Laravel 6 framework with laravel-elfinder to manage files.

Comment: If you can, open source it and share it!